# Laravel : Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails - Many to Many relationship

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, many-to-many, constraints

I know there's a bunch of problems asked about laravel integrity constraint violation, but none of them are Many to Many relationship, which is my case. Basically I have a table Hobi (hobby) and table Siswa (student), and the relationship is many to many since a student can have many hobbies and a hobby can be favored by many students. So here is the code :

This is my model Hobi :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Hobi extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'hobi';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nama_hobi',
    ];

    public function siswa(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Siswa', 'hobi_siswa', 'id_hobi', 'id_siswa');
    }
}
```

model Siswa :

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Siswa extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'siswa';

    protected $fillable = [
        'nisn',
        'nama_siswa',
        'tgl_lahir',
        'jns_klmin',
        'id_kelas',
        'id_hobi',
    ];

    public function hobi(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Hobi', 'hobi_siswa', 'id_siswa', 'id_hobi')->withTimeStamps();
}
}
```

A piece of form view code which contained Hobi :

```
@if($errors->any())
    <div class="form-group {{$errors->has('hobi') ? 'has-error' : 'has-success'}}">
@else
    <div class="form-group">
@endif
        {!! Form::label('hobi', 'Hobi:', ['class'=>'control-label']) !!}
        @if(count($hobi_list) > 0)
            @foreach($hobi_list as $key => $value)
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <label>{!! Form::checkbox('hobi[]', $value, null) !!}{{$value}}</label>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @else
            <p>Tidak ada pilihan hobi.</p>
        @endif
     </div>
```

And finally the controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

use App\Siswa;
use App\Telepon;
use App\Kelas;
use App\Hobi;

use Validator;

class SiswaCont extends Controller
{
    public function siswa(){
        $siswa_list = Siswa::orderBy('nama_siswa', 'asc')->paginate(10);
        $jmlh_siswa = Siswa::count();
        return view('siswa.ssw', compact('siswa_list', 'jmlh_siswa'));
    }

    public function create(){
        $kelas_list = Kelas::lists('nama_kelas', 'id');
        $hobi_list = Hobi::lists('nama_hobi', 'id');
        return view('siswa.create', compact('kelas_list', 'hobi_list'));
    }

    public function store(Request $request){
        $input = $request->all();

        $validator = Validator::make($input, [
            'nisn'=>'required|string|size:4|unique:siswa,nisn',
            'nama_siswa'=>'required|string|max:30', 
            'tgl_lahir'=>'required|date',
            'jns_klmin'=>'required|in:L,P',
no_telepon'=>'sometimes|numeric|digits_between:10,15|unique:telepon,no_telepon',
            'id_kelas'=>'required',
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect('siswa/create')->withInput()-  >withErrors($validator);
    }

        $siswa = Siswa::create($input);

        $siswa->hobi()->attach($request->input('hobi'));

        return redirect('siswa');
    }
}
```

I'm using pivot table hobi_siswa to contain id_siswa and id_hobi, creating a bridge. Hobi itself in form view is checkbox modeled. The problem is constraint, data Siswa for another column (nisn, nama_siswa, telepon, etc.) are saved, but Hobi not. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use `sync` method instead of `attach` which accepts an array.

From the [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

> The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table.

For example:

```
$user->roles()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
```

Comment: This is brief, but it's not link-only, it clearly states what to do even without the link.